# Protocol extension methods don't get called when protocol extends existing Apple API protocol

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, protocols, protocol-extension

I want a protocol to *inherit* from an Apple protocol `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`, add additional protocol requirements and provide a default implementation for some methods in that protocol. When I do that, the methods do not get called. When I implement the methods in the class itself, the methods *do* get called.

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, SlideDismissor {
    let transition: PercentDrivenInteractiveTransitionWithState? = PercentDrivenInteractiveTransitionWithState()
}

protocol SlideDismissor: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    var transition: PercentDrivenInteractiveTransitionWithState? { get }
}

extension SlideDismissor {
    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return nil // I do return something here, but for this example it isn't necessary
    }

    func interactionControllerForDismissal(animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return transition
    }
}
```

If I add the following code the functions do get called.

```
extension FirstViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return nil // I do return something here, but for this example it isn't necessary
    }

    func interactionControllerForDismissal(animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return transition
    }

}
```

These methods I'm trying to provide a default implementation for are optional methods.

Comment: I also experienced the same thing trying to provide default implementation for `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`

Answer (score 2):

The better solution for these kinds of problems is to use composition rather than inheritance. Rather than conform to `SlideDismissor`, delegate to one.

(I haven't tested this code or even made sure it compiles, but this is the basic approach I would explore.)

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    // Rather than handle your own transitioning, delegate it to another, reusable, object.    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Your original protocol suggested that the view controller wanted
        // to control what kind of transition was used, so we pass it as a paramater.
        transitioningDelegate = SlideDismissor(transition: PercentDrivenInteractiveTransitionWithState())
    }
}

// In that object, implement all the delegate methods
class SlideDismissor: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    let transition: PercentDrivenInteractiveTransitionWithState?

    init(transition: PercentDrivenInteractiveTransitionWithState?) {
        self.transition = transition
    }

    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return nil // I do return something here, but for this example it isn't necessary
    }

    func interactionControllerForDismissal(animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return transition
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to do something similar. Apparently a current limitation of protocol extensions seems to be that **we can't provide default implementations of Objective-C protocols**. Thus, any protocol declared in UIKit would fall under this category. This is also stated the the following recommended [article](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-9-tutorial-series-protocol-oriented-programming-with-uikit) about protocol-oriented programming.
this is valid as of september 2016.
I feel your pain =( but I guess for now this cleaner extension approach is not really feasible for the time being